# Is there a way to simulate a website button click without taking focus?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
var parentAction = document.querySelector("[title='Actions for Tab']");
var refreshButton = parentAction.getElementsByClassName("slds-truncate")[0].click();
```

This causes a specific tab to refresh on a website. I have it set up in a function with an interval set to run every 60 seconds. This runs without any issues.

However, a lot of the time this function will run while a user is typing in an input field. When the click happens it takes focus from the user typing and causes random windows to open on the page because of the keys they press. If they're not typing at the time, it's fine. They just have to click back into the input field and continue. This does get frustrating after a short time though.

Is there a better way to simulate the click event without taking focus from the input field they're typing in?

Comment: I'd suggest maybe adding an onfocus event to the input which will disable the interval.  Then handle the onblur event, which will re-enable the interval. That way your click event won't fire while the input has focus.

Comment: @MatthewM. That's actually the workaround I'm using now and it works. However, the reason for the refresh is to ensure the connection stays active. I found/tested that if a user or myself keeps the input field open and steps away from their computer for say 15 minutes then the refresh will never occur and it kicks them out. I appreciate your reply though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tab refreshes through ajax then why not just call a method
triggering the refresh action.

If you have to go that route:
The following is workaround that bypasses the refresh amidst user action;
it also includes a timer that kicks if user leaves during form dabblings.

```
var i = document.querySelector('input')
var inputFocus = false, pageTimer;
 
i.onfocus = () => {

    inputFocus = true;
    pageIdle()
}
  
i.onblur = () => { pageIdle() }


let refreshPage = () => {

   if (!inputFocus) console.log('page refresh')
}

let pageIdle = () => {
 
   console.log('user typing')
   if(pageTimer) clearTimeout(pageTimer)
   pageTimer = setTimeout(() => { inputFocus = false}, 6000)   <<  refreshes when users idles
}

setInterval(refreshPage, 2000)    <<  refreshes regularly 

document.onkeydown = () => {

   inputFocus = true 
   pageIdle()
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7co5yjnb/1/

Comment: This seems to work. I added a button and clicks onto your solution and it seems to be working. I'll test this with my extension and see if this addresses my issue. Thank you for your help.

https://jsfiddle.net/3mLrvdhn/6/